# Add legend for different colors of fill_between() segments

Tags: matplotlib

I am creating an "event plot" that is currently looking like this:

[image]

However, I don't know how I can add a legend just for each color group. This is how the plot gets created at the moment:

```py
handles = dict()

for i, channel_events in enumerate(channel_event_list):

    for event in channel_events:
        start = event[0]
        end = event[1]
        y = (i, i + padding)
        
        c = 'red' if colors is None else colors[i]

        h = plt.fill_between([start, end], y[0], y2=y[1], color=c)
        
        if c not in handles:
            handles[c] = list()
        handles[c].append(h)
```

I thought that I can use the output of `fill_between()` as handles but it seems I was mistaken there.

So what would be the easiest way to get a legend only for the colors here?

Comment: "But it seems I was mistaken" is not a sufficient problem description. I don't see why it shouldn't be possible to use the `PolyCollection` returned by `fill_between` as a legend handle.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To create a legend handle from a `fill_between` call, or just any other `PolyCollection` you can use this PolyCollection and supply it to the legend.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

h = plt.fill_between([1,2,3],[1,3,4], y2=[1,2,3], color="#c1009b")

plt.legend(handles=[h], labels=["MyLabel"])
plt.show()
```

[image]

An easier way is to directly use the `label` argument of the `fill_between` plot (just like any other plot) for creating automatic legend entries.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.fill_between([0,1,2],[4,3,4], y2=[3,2.5,3], color="#c1009b", label="Label1")
plt.fill_between([0,1,1.3],[1,2,0.5], y2=[0,-1,0], color="#005ec1", label="Label2")
plt.fill_between([2,3,4],[0.5,1,0], y2=[-1,-1,-1.5], color="#005ec1", label="_noLabel")

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you :)