# fill between vertical curves in the sub plot

Tags: python, matplotlib

Dears,
I have the following csv file

| depth | lst | dol | Anhd | sst |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 50 | 20 | 40 | 80 | 100 |
| 100 | 25 | 50 | 85 | 100 |
| 150 | 15 | 35 | 75 | 100 |

I take the data from csv to draw subplot contains four curves in the same subplot, I have filled by red color from left edge to first curve, also I have filled by blue color from last curve to right edge, I want to fill between entire curves in between first and last curve and make color legend.
the table is equal to csv file

````
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gridspec
import pandas as pd
import re
import json
test = r'D:\python\TEST-COMPOSITION.csv'
test =pd.read_csv(test)
mineral_names = test.drop(['depth'],axis=1)
mineral_names = list(mineral_names.columns.values)
colors = ["green", "gray"]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=1, ncols=10, wspace=0)
fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
for i in range(len(mineral_names)-1):

   plt.plot(test[mineral_names[i]],test['depth'],linewidth=2, color='black')
for i in range(len(mineral_names)-1):
    if i == 0:
      left_col_value = 0
      right_col_value = 100
      span = abs(left_col_value - right_col_value)
      cmap = plt.get_cmap('hot_r')
      color_index = np.arange(left_col_value, right_col_value, span / 100)
      for index in sorted(color_index):
        index_value = (index - left_col_value) / span
        plt.fill_betweenx(test['depth'],test[mineral_names[0]], left_col_value, where=test[mineral_names[i]] >= index, color="red")
    if i ==  range(len(mineral_names)-1)[-1]:
      left_col_value = 0
      right_col_value = 100
      span = abs(left_col_value - right_col_value)
      cmap = plt.get_cmap('hot_r')
      color_index = np.arange(left_col_value, right_col_value, span / 100)
      for index in sorted(color_index):
        index_value = (index - left_col_value) / span
        plt.fill_betweenx(test['depth'],test[mineral_names[i]], right_col_value, where=test[mineral_names[i]] >= index, color="blue")

    #if i ==1:
        #plt.fill_betweenx(test['depth'], test[mineral_names[i+1]], test[mineral_names[i]],color = "green", alpha=0.4)



plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
plt.show()```
````

Comment: This question does not have a complete [mre], which includes data.

Comment: About the legend to fill_between: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42836778/add-legend-for-different-colors-of-fill-between-segments . Does it answer your question?

Comment: Btw, what do you expect from ```range(len(mineral_names)-1)[-1]``` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an approach looping through the curves, and using a variable `previous_curve` which contains the position of the previous curve.  At the start, the previous curve is all zeros. Similarly, the name of the previous curve can be saved and used as a label for the fill. All labels will appear in the default legend.

The example code below uses a gridspec with only 4 columns, to make the example plot a bit clearer.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import gridspec
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

test = pd.DataFrame({'depth': [50, 100, 150],
                     'lst': [20, 25, 15],
                     'dol': [40, 50, 35],
                     'Anhd': [80, 85, 75],
                     'sst': [100, 100, 100]})
mineral_names = test.columns[1:]
fig = plt.figure(figsize=(15, 12), dpi=100, tight_layout=True)
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(nrows=1, ncols=4, wspace=0)

ax = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])
for mineral_name in mineral_names[:-1]:
    ax.plot(test[mineral_name], test['depth'], linewidth=2, color='black')

colors = ["red", "green", "gray", "blue"]
previous_curve = 0
previous_name = ''
for mineral_name, color in zip(mineral_names, colors):
    ax.fill_betweenx(test['depth'], previous_curve, test[mineral_name], color=color, alpha=0.4,
                     label=f'{previous_name} - {mineral_name}')
    previous_curve = test[mineral_name]
    previous_name = mineral_name
ax.margins(x=0, y=0)  # no white space in plot
ax.invert_yaxis()
ax.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: using fill_between_x for multiple curves]